# Magento Installation stuck at configuration

Tags: database, magento, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-9.10

I am not sure what is going wrong when I am trying to install magento to my local ubuntu machine. 
I did all the steps mentionsed in the [magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/installing_magento_on_ubuntu_8.0.4_with_xampp). Everything goes well until I reach the point where I am [here](http://localhost/magentosite/index.php/install/wizard/config/) which is the magento config page. When I try and continue after entering the necessary details like host, database name and user name and submit it comes back to the same page. I checked for everything like db in my phomyadmin panel and it still gets stuck there. What is the possible reason for that.

Thanks

Comment: Posting a link to http://localhost isn't massively helpful.  Are you getting any sort of error message on the page?

Comment: Nope. there is no error. It just takes back to the same page

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to create a database first and then proceed further.

Step 1 - First create a database with name of your choice like magento

Step 2 - Use that database name in the installation form now

Step 3 - Continue

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Why doesn't even the latest Version of Magento Show a proper error message to the user explaining this issue? :p :) Thanks for your solution!

Comment: @Christopher Stock - Maybe because they make their money selling support.

Comment: to check the credentials of the setup please go to xampp folder under this there will be a file called passwords you can get it from there for me i was giving wrong password this worked

Answer (score 17):

Have you try with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost ?
They have some trouble on login in the admin section.

And check the user/password in the config too !

Comment: Thank you. Fixed for installing localhost on Mac OSX Maverick

Answer (score 5):

I solved this modifing *app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml* (near 71th string) this

```
<extensions>
    <pdo_mysql/>
</extensions>
```

for this

```
<extensions>
    <pdo_mysql>1</pdo_mysql>
</extensions>
```

Answer (score 4):

Verify that you meet the following requirements:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements

Magento only runs on php 5.2.x, not 5.3. Also make sure the extensions listed on the requirements page are enabled.

Might be different for you, but I can check the php version using

php -v

**Edit**

Also what c-verde said about using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost:
This isn't your current problem, but you'll run into it later. You need to be able to accept cookies to log into Magento. Your browser won't accept cookies for local sites.

In /etc/hosts you need to add
127.0.0.1 localhost.com

And when you install magento you need to use either localhost.com or 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

I didn't have this problem with linux, but when installing on windows, it took several minutes after the config page to set up magento. Make sure the browser isn't doing anything.

Comment: Thanks Guys its fixed. I had edited my host file to www.localhost.com so all I had to do was in the magento config page use www.localhost.com as my host name.
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Before running the installation of **Magento**:

1. Navigate to the `Varien.php` file located in `magento/app/code/core/Mage/core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php`
2. You must **comment out the last 3 lines** in the `$cookieParams array`:

   ```
   $cookieParams = array(
       'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
       'path'     => $cookie->getPath()
       //'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
       //'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
       //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
   );
   ```

Comment: An explanation as to why to do this would help.

Answer (score 2):

Tick the box for

> Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step
>   Check this box only if it is not possible to automatically validate the Base URL.

I also added to my C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file

> 127.0.0.1 www.localhost.com

and removed my magento directory and database tables and started from scratch.

Works for me now.

Comment: If you are setting up a local instance of Magento (say, in a Vagrant setup with port other than 80) this is important to do! I did a lot of headbanging before I checked that box. Geez, this was for Magento 1.9.2 - would an error/result message been soooo hard to put into the installer?

Answer (score 2):

I did this and it worked!

Navigate to the Varien.php file located in magento/app/code/core/Mage/core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
You must comment out the last 3 lines in the $cookieParams array:

```
$cookieParams = array(
'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
'path'     => $cookie->getPath()
//'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
//'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
//'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
```

);

and if you got InnoDB error then do this
Go To Line 59 of the file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db/Mysql4.php

Use following code instead of current one

```
public function supportEngine()
{
$variables  = $this->_getConnection()
    ->fetchPairs('SHOW ENGINES');
return (isset($variables['InnoDB']) && $variables['InnoDB'] != 'NO');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you load php5-mysql extenion. Thats how I solved my problem.
I loaded with `http://localhost.com` (adding 127.0.0.1 localhost.com to /etc/hosts), it gave my error `load pdo-mysql php extension`. Otherwise with `http://localhost`, no error just reloading in configuration page)

Answer (score 1):

I had also been through this problem. I had just create the db first named "magento" and put the 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. I think, instead of 127.0.0.1, 'localhost' should also work if you had configure it. The problem might be because you didn't have the password for the database but you trying to put the password while installing the magento. Hope this helps some of them.

Comment: God! I searched all over the web and finally this solved my problem. Seriously got me frustated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out that I was missing a php module but no error was displayed. Megento are now providing a simple php script that checks if the required modules are available and displays an appropriate message if you are missing any of them.

You can find it here - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit username and password as 'root' and 'password' as per db setting

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be late for the PM, but probably useful to those who landed in this page via google.

My experience was that the whole configuration page is a blank page, without any form regarding database, user info or anything.

I fixed it by modifying the **{Megento Path}/app/etc/config.xml** file.

```
 <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host>localhost</host>
                <username/>
                <password/>
                <dbname>magento</dbname>
                <model>mysql4</model>
                <initStatements>SET NAMES utf8</initStatements>
                <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                <active>0</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
```

Change the value of the **host** item to anything other than localhost.
Then you get those forms and everything and can move on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the port name on which your mysql is running. Try using the port after your hostname for eg. localhost:3306 ,was my configuration settings along with database name and password of your mysql.